Prove that there are infinitely many triples of integers $(x, y, z)$ s.t. $x^2+y^2=(m^2+n^2)^{z}$ with positive integers $m, n$ and with $z$ even
To prove that there are infinitely many triples of integers $(x, y, z)$ such that $x^2+y^2=(m^2+n^2)^{z}$ with positive integers $m, n$ and with $z$ even, I tried to apply the parametric method, with the goal of finding an infinite family of solutions using $m$, $n$ and a positive integer $k$ such that $z=2k$, since it is even.
But for some reasons I can't find my way to a solution. I found one which jumps directly to the conclusion:
$$x=|m^{2}-n^{2}|(m^{2}+n^{2})^{k-1}; y=2mn(m^2+n^2)^{k-1}; z=2k$$
Can anybody explain me the thought process to come up with this solution?
I understood how to solve for $z$ odd, so with $z=2k+1$, with $k$ a positive integer:
$$(m^2+n^2)^{2k+1}=(m^2+n^2)^{2k}(m^2+n^2)=m^2(m^2+n^2)^{2k}+n^2(m^2+n^2)^{2k}$$
Yielding to the family of solutions $$(m(m^2+n^2)^{k}, n(m^2+n^2)^{k}, 2k+1)$$
It shouldn't be so hard to understand also how to come up with the solution for $z$ odd but I seem to have difficulties. Can anybody help?

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

@JoséCarlosSantos Done. Is it better?

Yes, it is better.

Everybody knows that solutions to $r^2+s^2=t^2$ are given by $r=m^2-n^2$, $s=2mn$, $t=m^2+n^2$. From that, it's immediate to get to your first displayed equation.

@GerryMyerson and that's what I found too. But how do you come up with that? I would like to understand the thought process

It's more of a reflex than a thought process. The formula for solutions of $r^2+s^2=t^2$, I've known since childhood. Anyone who studies right triangles with integer sides, a pretty natural thing for young math nerds to study, comes across it. Then, if you want $(m^2+n^2)^{2k}$ instead of just $m^2+n^2$, you just multiply everything by $(m^2+n^2)^{k-1}$.

If you merely want to prove there are infinitely many solutions without describing them comprehensively, you can readily prove there are infinitely many solutions with $z=2$. Note that every prime number $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ can be expressed uniquely as the sum of two squares i.e. $m^2+n^2$. Further note that each $p^2$ ($z=2$) will be a number of the form $4k+1$ and all numbers of that form can be expressed as the sum of two squares. There are infinitely many such primes $p$, so there are infinitely many such $p^2=x^x+y^2$

@GerryMyerson I posted the answer I was searching for. See, there is always a reason in everything. Be curious, always :)

If we want to understand why we use such a parametrization, we can refer to Brahmagupta-Fibonacci identity:
$$(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$$
Look what we have here: an identity of the form $$r^2+s^2=t$$. If only we could make that $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$ a square, we would have what we need to write the parametrisation. This can be done in 2 ways:

$a=c$ ^ $b=d$, giving $$(a^2+b^2)^2+(ab-ab)^2=(a^2+b^2)^2$$ leading us with nothing useful;
$a=d$ ^ $b=c$, giving $$(ab+ab)^2+(a^2-b^2)^2=(a^2+b^2)^2$$ that's what we wanted!

We can now solve in positive integers $(x, y, z)$ the equation $x^2+y^2=z^2$ with solutions of the form $$(2mn, m^2-n^2, m^2+n^2)$$ with positive integers $m, n$
Finally, we can go back to our equation $x^2+y^2=(m^2+n^2)^z$ and get solutions for $z=2k$ by considering $$x^2+y^2=[(m^2+n^2)^2]q$$ and the solutions
$$(2mnq, (m^2-n^2)q, 2k)$$
It's then easy to see that $$q=(m^2+n^2)^{2k-2}$$ because then in our equation it would multiply with $(m^2+n^2)^2$ to give what is requested.
Our final parametrization is the following:
$$(2mn(m^2+n^2)^{k-1}, (m^2-n^2)(m^2+n^2)^{k-1}, 2k)$$
